# Convert a column to multiple rows without knowing the names

Tags: r

Having a column such as the following

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c(
  "list(type = \"mac-addr\", spec_version = \"2.1\", id = \"mac-addr--PRIVATE_MAC_ID\", value = \"PRIVATE_MAC_ADDRESS\")",
  "list(type = \"indicator\", spec_version = \"2.1\", id = \"indicator--PRIVATE_INDICATOR_ID\", created_by_ref = \"identity--PRIVATE_CREATOR_ID\", created = \"PRIVATE_CREATED_TIME\", modified = \"PRIVATE_MODIFIED_TIME\", name = \"Malicious MAC Address\", description = \"Malicious MAC Address\", indicator_types = \"stix\", pattern = \"[mac-addr:value = 'PRIVATE_MAC_ADDRESS']\", pattern_type = \"stix\", pattern_version = \"2.1\", valid_from = \"PRIVATE_VALID_FROM\", lang = \"en\")")
)
```

how is it possible to create new column knowing that in every column all values are included in a list() text but we don't need it and every column name is before = and the value for every row is after = and every pair is separated by ,

Here an example of an expected output:

```
"type", "spec_version", "id", "value", "created_by_ref", "created", "modified", "name", "description", "indicator_types", "pattern", "pattern_type", "pattern_version", "valid_from", "lang"
"mac-addr", "2.1", "mac-addr--PRIVATE_MAC_ID", "PRIVATE_MAC_ADDRESS", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
"indicator", "2.1", "indicator--PRIVATE_INDICATOR_ID", NA, "identity--PRIVATE_CREATOR_ID", "PRIVATE_CREATED_TIME", "PRIVATE_MODIFIED_TIME", "Malicious MAC Address", "Malicious MAC Address", "stix", "[mac-addr:value = 'PRIVATE_MAC_ADDRESS']", "stix", "2.1", "PRIVATE_VALID_FROM", "en"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(col1 = gsub('list\\(|\\)$|"', '', col1), 
         row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(col1, ", ") %>%
  separate_wider_delim(col1, " = ", names = c("name", "value"), too_many = "merge") %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 2 × 15
#  type    spec_version id    value created_by_ref created modified name  description
#  <chr>   <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr>      
#1 mac-ad… 2.1          mac-… PRIV… NA             NA      NA       NA    NA         
#2 indica… 2.1          indi… NA    identity--PRI… PRIVAT… PRIVATE… Mali… Malicious …
# ℹ 6 more variables: indicator_types <chr>, pattern <chr>, pattern_type <chr>,
#   pattern_version <chr>, valid_from <chr>, lang <chr>
```

We remove `"list()"` text from `col1`, split the data on comma (`separate_longer_delim`), separate name and values pairs in different columns and get data in wider format.

Comment: thank you! It is quite close but I have more rows into the data and I receive this error: Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:
  * "type" at locations 1 and 4.
  * "id" at locations 2 and 6. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: From the error message it seems your data already has columns named `id` and `type` and hence when we `pivot_wider()` it cannot create duplicate column names. I would suggest to rename the already existing names, something like `data %>% rename(id1 = id, type1 = type) %>% mutate(....rest of the answer)`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a `dput()` output, so it can be parsed with `dget()`. As `dget()` accepts only filename or connection, the input string is first fed into `textConnection()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(col1 = c(
  "list(type = \"mac-addr\", spec_version = \"2.1\", id = \"mac-addr--PRIVATE_MAC_ID\", value = \"PRIVATE_MAC_ADDRESS\")",
  "list(type = \"indicator\", spec_version = \"2.1\", id = \"indicator--PRIVATE_INDICATOR_ID\", created_by_ref = \"identity--PRIVATE_CREATOR_ID\", created = \"PRIVATE_CREATED_TIME\", modified = \"PRIVATE_MODIFIED_TIME\", name = \"Malicious MAC Address\", description = \"Malicious MAC Address\", indicator_types = \"stix\", pattern = \"[mac-addr:value = 'PRIVATE_MAC_ADDRESS']\", pattern_type = \"stix\", pattern_version = \"2.1\", valid_from = \"PRIVATE_VALID_FROM\", lang = \"en\")")
)

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(parsed_list = textConnection(col1) %>% dget() %>% list(), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unnest_wider(parsed_list)  
#> # A tibble: 2 × 15
#>   type      spec_version id          value created_by_ref created modified name 
#>   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>       <chr> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>    <chr>
#> 1 mac-addr  2.1          mac-addr--… PRIV… <NA>           <NA>    <NA>     <NA> 
#> 2 indicator 2.1          indicator-… <NA>  identity--PRI… PRIVAT… PRIVATE… Mali…
#> # ℹ 7 more variables: description <chr>, indicator_types <chr>, pattern <chr>,
#> #   pattern_type <chr>, pattern_version <chr>, valid_from <chr>, lang <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>